# Unityエディターで実行を停止した後も、無限ループが実行されてしまう

Tags: c#, unity3d, .net

私は以下のようなasync/awaitを使ったプログラムを書きました。

```
private async void Start()
{
    while(true)
    {
        await test();
    }
}

private async Task test()
{
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    Debug.Log("3000");
}
```

このプログラムは実行時から3秒ごとに3000というログを表示するプログラムです。
このプログラムはUnityエディター上の再生ボタンを押し、再び再生ボタンを押して、実行を停止するまでは正常に動作します。
しかし、このプログラムは実行を停止した後も、3秒ごとに3000とログを表示し、その後しばらくすると表示しなくなります。実行を停止した時点で、ログを表示するのをやめさせるにはどうしたらよいでしょうか。

Unity2022.3.14f1
VisualStudio2022
.NetFramework

以下のようにしても、止まりませんでした。

```
bool next =true;
private async void Start()
{
    while(next)
    {
        await test();
    }
}

private async Task test()
{
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    Debug.Log("3000");
}

private void OnApplicationQuit()
{
    next = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

以下のようにスクリプトを変更したら、意図した動作をしました。
キャンセレーショントークンを使用しました。

```
private CancellationTokenSource cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
private CancellationToken token;

private async void Start()
{
    token = cancellation.Token;

    while(next)
    {
        await test(token);
    }
}

private void OnApplicationQuit()
{
    next = false;
    cancellation.Cancel();
}
```